# how to get value of radio button and display on text view (Java for android)

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrPji.png)
this the XML structure for the radio button group
i try alot of code but nothnig good

Comment: Did you implement a setOnClickListener() ? What is your current java code for getting the value?

Comment: Please [edit] and put your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity you will need to use `findViewById` to create Views in Java to connect to your layout `RadioGroup` and `TextView`. You will need to register a listener on your `RadioGroup` to detect changes to the selection and then pass the result to your `TextView`.

Provide the code you've tried and I'll update my answer with specific suggestions to help you fix it.